# Compare the date column in datagridview with month of datetime c# winform

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview, account

I want to calculate the asset depreciation by comparing the current date and the date of purchase. I need help because I am doing this quarterly. Compare the date of every quarter with the date of purchase and than calculate the total depreciation to today's date. Any Help?

Comment: If you provide any code it whould be helpfull.

Comment: It would be better to create a [MCVE] demonstrates your problem. Also please read [ask] couple of times..

Comment: I would make the DataSource of the view a datatable and then filter the datatable.  I would use a GroupBy using the Month and year of the datetime object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an accountant.  Below get you the arrays from a datatable :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication61
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Purchased Date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(decimal));


            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Item A",DateTime.Parse("11/5/2014"), 1000.00 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Item B",DateTime.Parse("2/20/2015"), 1000.00 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Item C",DateTime.Parse("4/5/2016"), 1000.00 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Item D",DateTime.Parse("8/5/2017"), 1000.00 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Item E",DateTime.Parse("9/3/2018"), 1000.00 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Item F",DateTime.Parse("1/5/2015"), 1000.00 });


            DateTime startDate = dt.AsEnumerable().Min(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Purchased Date"));
            DateTime startQuarter = new DateTime(startDate.Year, (3 * (startDate.Month / 3)) + 1, 1 );

            double depreciationRate = .99; //rate per quarter

            DateTime[] quarters = Enumerable.Range(0, (((DateTime.Now - startQuarter).Days) / 90) + 1).Select(x => startQuarter.AddMonths(3 * x)).ToArray();

            var depreciation = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    item = x.Field<string>("Name"),
                    depreciation = quarters
                        .Select(y => x.Field<DateTime>("Purchased Date") > y ? 0 : x.Field<decimal>("Price") *(decimal) Math.Pow(depreciationRate, ((y - x.Field<DateTime>("Purchased Date")).Days) / 90)).ToList()
                })
                .ToList();


        }
    }
}
```